# Event loop iterating not as intended

Tags: python-3.x, loops, event-loop

I have been having problems with this lab assignment for class. I want to ensure that my input is the specified enumerate, and not any other input. But for some reason I can't seem to get it to work properly, even when I put in an incorrect answer it just runs through the loop until I input the right answer. I am not experienced to know what I'm not seeing.

```
questions = [
    {'question': '\nOverall what is your response?',
     'answers': ['Calmly look around?',
                'Panic!!',
                'Roll over and cry?'],
    'correct': '1'},
    {'question': '\nYou notice a door. Do you try it?',
     'answers': ['Yes',
                'No'],
     'correct': '1'},
    {'question': '\nYou smell something strange in the corner. What do you do?',
     'answers': ['Investigate?',
                'Do you poke it?',
                'Leave it alone?',
                 'Vomit'],
     'correct':'1'},
    {'question': '\nA light flickerss above you. What do you do?',
     'answers': ['Break it!!',
                'Tighten it.',
                'Leave  it alone.',
                'Roll over'],
     'correct': '2'},
    {'question': '\nThe bed you woke up in seems strange..',
     'answers': ['Roll it over.',
                'Roll over and cry.',
                'Go to bed.'],
     'correct': '1'},
    {'question': '\nIn one corner a is playing Tiny Tim. What do you do?',
     'answers': ['Turn it off',
                'Mess with the dials',
                'Sing along',
                'Watch the show, continuously'],
     'correct': '1'},
    {'question': '\nThe door knob creeks',
     'answers': ['Jump through the roof',
                'Run to it',
                'Wait calmly',
                'Yell!'],
     'correct': '3'},
    {'question': '\nYou notice a cellar door in the corner',
     'answers': ['Try to open it',
                'Cautiously approach it',
                'Forcfully open',
                'Yell at it'],
     'correct': '1'},
    {'question': '\nA loud speaker is on the ceiling, starts playing Tiny Tim',
     'answers': ['Sing along',
                'Panic even more',
                'Embrace the Tiny Tim',
                'Try and destroy the loud speaker'],
     'correct': '4'},
    {'question': '\nYou see a toilet of needeles. What do you do?',
     'answers': ['Reach your arm into it.',
                'Question the needles in the toilet.',
                'Check the tank.',
                'Roll over.'],
     'correct': '3'}
            ]    
score = 0
for question in questions:
    print(question['question'])

    for i, choice in enumerate(question['answers']):
        print(str(i + 1) + '. ' + choice)

    answer = ''

    while answer not in range(1, len(question['answers'])):
        answer = input('Choose a numerical answer: ')

        if answer == question['correct']:
            score = score
            break
        elif answer in question['answers']:
            break

    if answer == question['correct']:
        score = score + 1

    else:
        print('That\'s one way to try it...')
```

Comment: Can you post 'questions' dict?

Comment: I added the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that you are comparing a string answer to a list of integers produced by range.

Try converting the list of ints to a list of strings.

```
while answer not in [str(x) for x in range(1, len(question['answers']))]:
```

Comment: Thanks that helped much more. Now however I can't seem to be able to choose whichever is the last item in the answers without it looping infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

```
score = 0
for question in questions:
    print(question['question'])

    for i, choice in enumerate(question['answers'], 1):   #enumerate start from 1
        print(str(i) + '. ' + choice)

    c = map(int, range(1, len(question['answers'])+1))      #Convert your choice list to int
    answer = input('Choose a numerical answer: ')

    while answer not in c:     #Check if input in available choice list. 
        answer = input('Choose a numerical answer: ')        

    if answer == question['correct']:
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print('That\'s one way to try it...')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that converting the range to strings and then adding on to the length worked perfectly. Which was provided by both of the answers I received here.

```
    while answer not in [str(x)
                         for x in(range(1, len(question['answers'])+1))]:

        answer = input('Choose a numerical answer: ')

        if answer == question['correct']:
            score = score
            break

    if answer == question['correct']:
        score = score + 1
```